# Expose variable to javascript context (Java / WebView)

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I want to expose a variable (a value) to the global javascript context.
I **don't** want to expose an interface. I **don't** want to expose functions. I want to expose a single  value in the **global** context of javascript, meaning that the value should be accessible with `window.my_value;`.

I tried overriding the `onPageFinished` method and running `evaluateJavascript`, but that seems to trigger way too late for my app to read the value (by the time the variable is set, my app is already running and has already read the `undefined` value of `my_value`).

Is there a way I can inject my variable, somehow, into the page I'm loading, as soon as possible, before any other JS has been loaded?

Answer (score -1):

Very simply

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    a = 100;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(a);
    // rest of your javascript code
</script>
```

There is no need for these to be in separate script tags, but for demonstration purposes, I'll leave those.

Unless there is some vital information missing from your question, this is fairly straightforward. As you say, you want this to be set before any of your other javascript is ran. Therefore, to achieve that, set the global variable before any of your other javascript is ran.

Comment: I want to expose/inject the variable from the java code in my Android app. I don't have control over the website.

Comment: That would be the vital information I mentioned then.

Comment: The part where I mention that I tried overriding `onPageFinished` and ran `evaluateJavascript`, and the tags "java" and "android-webview" didn't trigger any bells?

Comment: No, because I don't work with android apps and therefore I wouldn't know what onPageFinished and evaluateJavascript methods are responsible for doing. You can't assume others will know that either. For all I know, you're having difficulty running some javascript on a webpage you're trying to load on an android device.

Comment: So... you didn't understand half of the question, but still you posted an answer?

Comment: I understood the question as it was written. Nowhere in your question does it state that you're writing java code for an android app. You can't expect somebody to gather that from the tags. I don't really want an argument over something so daft, so have a nice day sir and I hope somebody is able to understand the question well enough to help you :)

Comment: The question is well-worded. The problem is that you just skipped the parts that didn't understand.

Comment: I disagree, and so do you as you felt the need to edit your title after I'd answered.

Comment: I edited the title to avoid more people that don't understand the question posting answers.

Comment: That said, please, can you remove your answer?

Comment: No, but feel free to downvote it if you feel I haven't provided an adequate solution to what you asked (how to have some javascript run before some other javascript, as per your question). Again, have a nice day :)